# how to convert int[] into model item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

For my project I used web service for fetch data from database. getAvailableList() method is available in that service and it returns int[] array. I want to convert this into object and want to pass it into View. 
below is Action method.

```
public ActionResult Ataxi()
    {
        var alist = IM.getAvailableList();
        return View(alist);
    }
```

this is my View

```
@model List<WEB1.Models.sub_employee>
@foreach(var item in Model){
if (item.SE_ID != null)
     {
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SE_ID)
     }
}
```

I got error message of The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WEB1.Models.sub_employee]'. how do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you post get available item list method.

Comment: it is located in WSDL web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is strongly typed with WEB1.Models.sub_employee object so you can not pass int[] to your view that is what the compiler complaining about. if
IM.getAvailableList() method returns all sub_employee.SE_ID as a int[] and SE_ID is int32 then you can construct the sub_employee list like below and pass it. using the System.Linq Namespace.

```
var alist = IM.getAvailableList();
    return View(alist.Select(x => new WEB1.Models.sub_employee { SE_ID = x }).ToList());
```

Comment: furthermore I want to find item from sub_employee class where SE_ID equals alist

Comment: You can filter the list using where condition like ....var alist = IM.getAvailableList();
    return View(alist.where(x=>x==123)Select(x => new WEB1.Models.sub_employee { SE_ID = x }).(x.ToList());

Comment: Or you can traverse the the sub_employee list like .where(x=>x.SE_ID=1234)

Comment: there are lot of ids in `alist` I want to find all ids which are avaialble in sub_employee model

Comment: Do you have sub_employee Model list separately.if so then you can filter the Sub_employee list like.. sub_employee.Where(x => alist.Contains(x.SE_ID));

Answer (score 0):

Check the return type of the method. It is not returning the list of employee. Its returning int. and as you are fetching the result in var alist, compiler is nor complaining about the data type but when you are passing it to your view as view is strongly typed hence it is complaining. Check wsdl document and find out the return type of the method.